# Dialog doesn't return the appropriate condition vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the MetroFramework and apparently I have a problem with this code:

```
Dim result As String = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Confirm?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Me.Close() 
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        'nothing..
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        My.Settings.Save()
        MsgBox("Saved succesful")
    End If
```

If the user confirms the message that appears the condition is not activated, and this is quite strange because before using the MetroFramework this works. What is the problem then?

Comment: you call it specifying `OKCancel` but then test "yes", and "no"

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: If you want to test for Yes, No, or Cancel, you need to use `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel`. You've specified `MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel`, which means there is no `DialogResult.Yes` or `DialogResult.No` returned. (You'll receive `DialogResult.OK` or `DialogResult.Cancel`, nothing else.)

Comment: Ahh!! You are right, now it seems to work!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify one expected result in the call (`OKCancel`) but then proceed to test for `Yes` and `No`.  Make them match for the IF to work:

```
Dim result As String = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Confirm?", "Warning",
           MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, 
           MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    Me.Close() 
ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
    'nothing..
ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
    My.Settings.Save()
    MsgBox("Saved succesful")
End If
```

Note the change of the 4th param to `MessageBox` from `MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel` to `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel`